# Auto order an array based on Json key value

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I created this code to reference a Json array and built a list:

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('events.json');

    $jsonArray = json_decode($json, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array

    foreach ($jsonArray as $value) {

        if (($value['active'] === 't') && ($value['fromDate'] >= $currentDate)) {

            echo '<p>'.$value['title'].' '.$value['fromDate'].' - '.$value['toDate'].'</p>';
        }
    }

    echo $currentDate;  
?>
```

However, I can't figure out how to organize by a value in the Json file:

```
[
    {

        "active": "f",
        "title": "My Third Event",
        "city": "Robert Downey Jr.",
        "ST": "Robert Downey Jr.",
        "fromDate": "01/17",
        "toDate": "01/20",
        "website": "http://google.com",
        "email": "info@test.com",
        "logo": ""
    },
    {

        "active": "t",
        "title": "My First Event",
        "city": "Robert Downey Jr.",
        "ST": "Robert Downey Jr.",
        "fromDate": "05/12",
        "toDate": "01/20",
        "website": "http://google.com",
        "email": "info@test.com",
        "logo": ""
    }
]
```

I want to use "fromDate" to dynamically organize each entry when loaded. Any advise?
FYI - i have reviewed the PHP manual and other SO entries, but i'm new to PHP and Ive not got my head totally wrapped around the concepts just yet. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to order your array by the key `toDate` ?!

Comment: Yes. order each entry by fromDate... not toDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just sort your array with [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) by comparing the timestamps of the "fromDate".

```
usort($jsonArray, function($a, $b) {
    if(strtotime($a["fromDate"]) == strtotime($b["fromDate"]))
        return 0;
    return strtotime($a["fromDate"]) > strtotime($b["fromDate"])? 1: -1;
});
```

Comment: Guiness! that worked. However I may need to dynamically get the year as it will eventually change.

Comment: @trobbins26 You're welcome! See my updated answer, forgot that strtotime() just takes the current year if you don't add one, so it should all works fine